# Install WordPress with SQL Server 2008 or 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, wordpress

I am trying to install WordPress to SQL Server 2008 or 2012.

Environment: WordPress 4.0, PHP 5.4, IIS 8.5, PHP Manager, php_mssql.dll php_sqlsrv php_pdo_sqlsrv enable

At this moment I am using wp-db-abstraction to try to get this connection. I have followed the instructions of this post  http://blog.rajenki.com/2012/12/wordpress-on-windows-server-2012-with-iis-8-and-sql-server-2012/ but I can't establish connection to my SQL Server database.

I have checked my `wp-config.php` file, I have check my php drivers, now I have no idea what else to check.

- Does anyone had any suggestion for me at this point?
- Some PHP configuration I should change?
- Any other plugin I could use?

Thanks,

Sofia

Comment: I am going to try it in next few weeks/days.. A few weeks ago I managed to install WordPress 3.0 on SQL Server 2008 R2 following these instructions http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/installing-wordpress-on-windows-using-sql-server-2008-r2-part-1 also you might come to some issues so read related comments or Google specific errors..

Comment: Vaciav,
Could you tell me a little more about your environment? You mention Wordpress3.0, Does the PHP version matter?? I see pho_pdo_sqlsrv_53 in the document, did you use PHP 5.3??

Comment: Actually does but I don't remember the reason anymore. I used PHP 5.3 with pho_pdo_sqlsrv_53. I think I tried also 5.4 including the driver but didn't manage to run it..